# Is there a way to set parameters to navigation in a screen befor navigationOption load in react native 0.60

Tags: react-native

I have an Edit page, when a user selects the desired color and icon, click on the Save button on the header of my screen and this selected color and icon save on Asyncstorage and back to the main page.
I store color and icon in the state of my Edit page, and I have a function named SaveChanges() that saves this color and icon on Asyncstorage and returns back to the main page.
I want to call this function when the save button on the header is clicked.
But in navigationOption:
1-I cannot access this(as this page)
2-navigationOption called before componentDidMount, so setParam in componentDidMount does not affect on navigationOption.

```
componentDidMount() {

     this.props.navigation.setParams({ saveChanges: this.saveChanges });
   }

saveChanges=()=>{
     console.warn("in save changes");
     asyncstorage.SetinfoInAsyncstorage(this.props.lable,{issuer:this.state.issuerName,color:this.state.selectedColor,icon:this.state.selectedIcon}, (mymessage) =>
     {
        const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
          index: 0,
           actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'AllAccountInfo',params:{allaccountmessage:mymessage} })],
          });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);



     });
   }

   static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
     return {
       headerRight: (
         <MaterialHeaderButtons>
           <Item buttonStyle={{color:'black'}}  title="save" iconName="save" onPress={()=>{
             navigation.getParam('saveChanges');
             }} />
         </MaterialHeaderButtons>

       ),
     };
   };
```

The documents for the navigation says that I have to use redux. But I do not want redux because it complexes my app.
When I search, the title of the header dynamically changes, but I cannot see headerRight.

Comment: I find my answer:)

Comment: Please, upload you answer as other users may find it useful for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this.props.navigation.setParams in componentDidMount I set all thing that I need to show in headerRight not just a function.

```
var that = this;
  this.props.navigation.setParams({ headerRight: 
  <MaterialHeaderButtons>
    <Item buttonStyle={{color:"white"}}  title="save" iconName="save" onPress={
      ////save color icon and application_name name in asyncstorage
      function(){
       asyncstorage.SetAccountinfoInAsyncstorage(that.user_id,{application_name:that.state.application_name,color:that.state.selectedColor,icon:that.state.selectedIcon}, (mymessage) =>
       {
          const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
             actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'AllAccountInfo' })],
            });
            that.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);



       });

      }} />
  </MaterialHeaderButtons>,
  primaryColor : this.props.theme.colors.primary,
  textColor:this.props.theme.colors.text,
  surfaceColor:this.props.theme.colors.surface,
  dark:this.props.theme.dark
  });
```